# Updating database using threads

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update a huge number of records using .net core and entity framework core, now the question that I can't get a clear answer on is:
If I used many threads to do the job, Should I give each thread a new instance of the database context or all threads can work on the same instance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you fix your tag from ef 6 to ef core?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Done.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's entirely useful or related, but I've written a [database seeder for one of my EF Core 2.0 projects](https://github.com/GaProgMan/dwCheckApi/blob/master/dwCheckApi.Persistence/Helpers/DatabaseSeeder.cs) which uses Tasks and SaveChangesAsync to add a large number of records to the database. I wonder whether it would of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a separate instance to each thread. Using the same context for all threads will result in using the same SQL connection which is not correct.

Just to make sure to balance the number of threads to avoid getting out of connections.

Comment: Will do, Thanks a lot. :)